# Is it necessary to serialise read/write accesses to a CGLayer in OSX?

Tags: macos, concurrency, core-graphics, cglayer

My Mac OSX application has a background process that uses Core Graphics to  draw 2D lines and areas into a `CGLayer`. This is then periodically displayed to the user via the `displayRect()` method of an `NSView` subclass.

At the moment I'm using a GCD queue to serialise the tasks that read and write to the layer. This ensures that the background process can never be drawing on it at the same time the main thread draws it into the view using `CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint()`. However, this costs me some performance.

**Question 1:** Is the serialisation of R/W accesses to the `CGLayer` necessary for the stability of the app? (I don't mind the odd mis-displayed image, but I don't want to risk a crash).

**Question 2:** If I were to split the drawing task into several concurrent processes, would it be safe to allow them to all write to the layer at the same time or would I need to serialise them (which would make the concurrency kind of pointless)?

Answer (score 0):

OK so having done some testing I can say the answer to Question (2) is **NO** it is **NOT** safe to let two different processes write simultaneously to the same `CGLayer`.

When I tried doing two simultaneous `CGContextFillRect()` actions on the same layer, the application terminated abnormally with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS() code=1`.

However the answer to Question (1) is that is **DOES** seem to be alright to do a simultaneous read of a `CGLayer` while a background process is still writing it. For instance here is the result of reading a layer while a background process is in the process of overwriting all the red squares with blue ones.[image]